# Changing column value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Normally used to MySQL so need help on syntax check.

with
`SELECT * FROM Bit WHERE CustomerID='3512242'` I have a field called Filer. I want to change it from a P to a D. Do I use `UPDATE` to change the value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE dbo.Bit
  SET Filer = 'D'
  WHERE CustomerID = '3512242'
  AND Filer = 'P';
```

[Documentation for UPDATE with many examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

Comment: oops i didn't see that when i read the mysql ,thought she looking for mysql syntax

Comment: @Bijujose The syntax for updating one table is pretty much the same in MySQL, too.